# How to use protobuf descriptor to read enums

Tags: c++, enums, protocol-buffers

Let's say I have a .proto file with:

```
message Foo {
  optional int32 x = 1;
  enum y {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
  }
  optional string z = 3;
}
```

Then I have this C++ code which prints all the types:

```
 const Reflection *refl = Foo.GetReflection(); 
 const Descriptor *desc = Foo.GetDescriptor();

 int fieldCount = desc->field_count();
 for(int i=0;i<fieldCount;i++){
     const FieldDescriptor *field = desc->field(i);
     cout  << field->name().c_str() << " the type is " 
           <<field->type_name()<< ": Type Number "<< field->type() <<endl;

     if(field->type()==FieldDescriptor::TYPE_ENUM){
         //do something
     }
```

The output is then:

```
    x the type is int32: Type Number 5
    z the type is string: Type Number 9
```

As seen in the output, the enum is skipped, how would I get the field descriptor to parse over the enum as well?

Comment: Use `EnumDescriptor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have a field of your Enum type, you have only defined a type. Because of that, your iteration over fields doesn't yield anything related to the enum.

If you add a field of a given type, you will see your enum there.